# How to prevent for calling specific screen controller calls in Segment Analytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, segment-analytics

I want to prevent the call of `[[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] screen:name properties:nil options:nil];` which is happening inside the method `seg_viewDidAppear` in Segment Analytics. It gets call for every controller. I have a `UITabBarController` in appdelegate which has 5 controllers in it. So this `[[SEGAnalytics sharedAnalytics] screen:name properties:nil options:nil];` gets call and prints `UITabBarController` multipule time. I can put a condition in `seg_viewDidAppear` specifically for `UITabBarController` but i was wondering if there is any other way to prevent it.

Thanks in advance.